# Find and replace with regular expression C#

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio, replace

I need to find the mentioned lambda statement and remove it from my code. My project is so big, and I noticed in the find and replace box of Visual Studio, there is an argument that can use regular expressions to find and replace codes. Is there a regular expression that can find this statement completely (contains line break and white space also)?

```
() =>
      {
        CallMethod()
      },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that VS IDE is using the regular expressions in single line mode (which is actually strange considering that it offers \n in the suggestion menu). I think you will be a lot better creating a new project, which will load the file, read all text from it, and replace whatever regex you specify, and then save the file back.

Basically the regex you need is this:

```
(\(\ *\)\ *=\>[\r\n\s\{\}]*CallMethod\ *\(\ *\)[\r\n\s\{\}]*,)
```

In C# code, you can do it like this:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"(\(\ *\)\ *=\>[\r\n\s\{\}]*CallMethod\ *\(\ *\)[\r\n\s\{\}]*,)", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Multiline);
regex.Replace(document, string.Empty);
```

Hope this will be of help to you.